# Draw colored ellipses with text at any position

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to present keywords on a beamer slide. What I imagine is ellipses with colors and text inside (different font sizes possible). I would like to position and resize these freely on the slide by specifying coordinate/size values.

Can someone provide a minimal example? I suppose that tikz is capable of doing that but I have no idea what to specifically do there and couln't find an example that does what I want. It doesn't need to be beautiful, it just needs to work.

```
% This does not work for me because I cannot position the ellipses 
% in absolute coordinates on the slide.
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikz\draw[fill=orange!30!white] at (0,0) ellipse (20pt and 28pt);
  \tikz\draw[fill=orange!60!white] at (1,0) ellipse (28pt and 20pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Why did you put `\tikz` before `\draw`?

Comment: I merely copied this. Thanks for the hint. I thought it has to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs two runs to align properly (because of the `remember picture`
option).

The command `\myellipse` has the following syntax: First optional
argument is additional stuff you want to pass to the optional argument of
`\node`. After that are the coordinates in `(x,y)` syntax. `x` and `y` are
interpreted as multiples of `\textwidth` and `\textheight`, respectively. The
next optional argument is the colour you want to apply to the ellipse. Finally
the mandatory argument is the content of the ellipse.

Spaces around it have to be set explicit (using a backslash and a following space) after the command or by putting a `\kern0pt` after the space. This is due to the usage of `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces`.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{%
  myellipse/.style={ellipse, draw=#1!70!black, fill=#1!30,inner xsep=0pt}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myellipse{}% check whether it is already defined
\def\myellipse%
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[% ]
      {\myellipse@i}
      {\myellipse@i[]}%
  }
\def\myellipse@i[#1](#2,#3)%
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[% ]
      {\myellipse@ii{#1}{#2}{#3}}
      {\myellipse@ii{#1}{#2}{#3}[orange]}%
  }
\def\myellipse@ii#1#2#3[#4]#5%
  {%
    \unskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[myellipse=#4,xshift=#2\paperwidth,yshift=#3\paperheight,#1]
        at (current page.south west) {#5};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \ignorespaces
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \myellipse[anchor=north east](.4,.4){foo}
  \myellipse(.5,.5)[red]{bar}
  \myellipse(.6,.6)[violet]{baz}
  \myellipse(.7,.7)[blue]{\large size matches the contents}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

with bides with ellipse shape:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shadows,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Keywords}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
     E/.style = {% E as ellipse
    ellipse, draw=#1!70!black, fill=#1!30,
    inner xsep=0pt, drop shadow}
                        ]
\node (n1) [E=orange] {important};
\node (n2) [E=red, right=of n1] {word};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```