# How to Draw Ellipses in Tikz with an Axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I am trying to convert the picture below into Tikz:

[image]

I tried using the following code as a starting point:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xticklabels={,,},
yticklabels={,,},
xlabel={Volatility Protection},
ylabel={Impact on Client Investment Performance}]
\end{axis}

\tikz \draw[fill=red!20] (12,5) ellipse (40pt and 10pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

However, I'm not really getting close and there seems to be an issue with my code where adjusting the (12,5) does not move the ellipse in the way I'd expect.

Could someone point me in the right direction for how to make this graphic in Tikz? Even if you can get axes and one ellipse I could take it from there and fill in the rest, I mostly just am looking for a good template to get started with. Thanks!!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418437/197451

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251263/197451

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515588/194703) give you a start? It is really not hard to do this, but what frightens some of us off from providing an explicit answer is that one would have to type in all the texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various strategies available to draw something like this. One approach is to [draw the ellipses and to add the text afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515588/194703). This approach has the disadvantage that if you change the texts a lot, you need to change tons of coordinates. Therefore, here `positioning` is used to place the ellipses relative to each other. This requires one to use elliptical nodes, and thus little tricks are employed to move the text inside the nodes. What is better depends on the case and personal taste.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,font=\sffamily,
    elli/.style args={#1 and #2}{ellipse,minimum width=#1cm,
    minimum height=#2cm,align=center}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=ells,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1]
   \node[elli=3.5 and 2,fill=blue] (E1) {independent solution};
   \node[elli=3 and 2.8,fill=cyan,above right=0em and -1em of E1.east] (E2) {Capped violity funds};
   \node[elli=2.8 and 2.8,fill=cyan!80,above=-3em of E2] (E3) {Asset-transfer\\
   programs\\[3em]};
   \node[elli=3 and 3.4,fill=gray,right=-2em of E3.10,inner sep=-0.5em] (E4){
   \quad\begin{tabular}{c}Target viotatility\\
     funds
    \end{tabular}};
  \node[elli=3 and 4,fill=gray!70,above=-1em of E4.north] (E5) 
   {Capital preservation\\ funds\\[2em]};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[gray,thin] ([shift={(-1ex,1ex)}]ells.north west) coordinate (TL) rectangle 
  ([shift={(1ex,-1ex)}]ells.south east)coordinate (BR) -- (TL);
  %
  \draw[thick,<->] ([yshift=-2em]BR-|TL) node[below right]{Low} 
   -- node[above] {Economic \dots} ([yshift=-2em]BR) node[below left]{High};
  % 
  \draw[thick,<->] ([xshift=-2em]TL) node[below left,rotate=90]{Significant
  impact}    -- node[above,rotate=90] {Economic \dots} 
   ([xshift=-2em]TL|-BR) node[below right,rotate=90]{Minimal impact};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]